# Proving that the curvature of the induced connection satisfies $k_{\nabla^{*}}(X,Y) = k_{\nabla}(X, Y)^{*}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, connections, dual-maps

I am trying to make Exercise 19 of these [lecture notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_AK0HGxgYXJas46SWFxTmbNR0eCCTH2/view).
I'll briefly summarize the question below.

> **Exercise** Let $V$ be a dinite dimensional vector space and $A \in \mathrm{End}(V)$. We consider
> $$
> A^* \in \mathrm{End}(V^*), \quad \text{given by } A^*(\xi)(v) = \xi(A(v)).
> $$
> We keep the same notation for endomorphisms of vector bundles.
> Show that the curvature of $\nabla^*$ is given by
> $$
> k_{\nabla^*}(X,Y) = k_{\nabla}(X,Y)^*.
> $$

The lecture notes use the following definition of curvature:

> **Definition** For any connection $\nabla$ on a vector bundle $E \to M$, the curvature is given by
> $$
> k_{\nabla}(X,Y)s = \nabla_X \nabla_Y(s) - \nabla_Y \nabla_X(s) - \nabla_{[X,Y]}, 
> $$
> where $X,Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, $s \in \Gamma(E)$ and $[\cdot, \cdot]$ denotes the Lie bracket.

So it is viewed as a map $\mathfrak{X}(M) \times \mathfrak{X}(M) \times \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(E)$ (or $k_{\nabla} \in \Gamma(\Lambda^2 T^*M \otimes \mathrm{End}(E)) = \Omega^2(M; \mathrm{End}(E)).)$.

Also, the induced connection $\nabla^*$ on $E^*$ is characterized by the equation
$$
L_X(\xi(s)) = \nabla_X^*(\xi)(s) + \xi(\nabla_X(s)).
$$

I have attempted this exercise by writing both sides out, but it gets very messy very quickly. Is there a smarter way to tackle this question, or is it a matter of really diligently writing everything out and hoping for the best? If that's the case, I am afraid I will have more questions, but that's a worry for later ;)

Thanks in advance for the advice or help! :)

Comment: It would be possible to give a computationally light proof using principal connections, but that material comes much later in the notes, and learning all that will be a lot more effort than just working out this exercise with a direct computation. Where are you getting stuck? Also, I think the formula should be $k_{\nabla^\ast}(X,Y) = -k_\nabla(X,Y)^\ast$.

Comment: Ah I was afraid that'd be the case. Well, if I write out $\nabla_X^* \nabla_Y^*(\xi)(s)$ I get $\nabla_X(L_X(\xi(s)) - \xi(\nabla_X(s)))$, and I don't really understand how I should write out $\nabla_X(L_X(\xi(s)))$ for instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the core step of the computation:

$$ \nabla_X^\ast \nabla_Y^\ast (\xi)(s) = \nabla_X^\ast (\nabla_Y^\ast (\xi))(s) = L_X (( \nabla_y^\ast \xi)(s)) - (\nabla_Y^\ast)(\nabla_Xs) \\ 
= L_X(L_Y\xi(s) - \xi(\nabla_Ys))-L_Y\xi(\nabla_X s)+\xi(\nabla_Y\nabla_Xs) \\= L_X L_Y\xi(s) - L_X \xi(\nabla_Ys)-L_Y\xi(\nabla_X s)+\xi(\nabla_Y\nabla_Xs) .$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Oh wow! I made a critical mistake, I interpreted it as $\nabla_X^\ast \nabla_Y^\ast (\xi)(s) = \nabla_X^\ast (\nabla_Y^\ast (\xi)(s))$, which made everything so much harder. Thank you so much for clearing everything up, I will be able to take it from here.

Comment: I made the same mistake at first too. Happy to help!